# AttributeError: Outlook.Application.Logon

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to save Outlook email to a folder using Python.

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Outlook.Application.Logon.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

My code:

```
import win32com.client

def main():  

    session = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    session.Logon('Outlook') 
    inbox = session.Inbox
    message = inbox.Messages.GetLast()
    attachments = message.Attachments
    for i in range(attachments.Count):
        attachment = attachments.Item(i + 1)
        filename = 'C:\EMAILS\tempfile_%i' % i
        attachment.WriteToFile(filename)
    session.Logoff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook automation object `Application.Outlook` does not have a member called `Logon`, that's why it's failing.

The documentation for `Application.Outlook` is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You should rename `session` to `application` because the object represents the root of Outlook's automation model, it does not refer to a particular application session.

The rest of your code is incorrect too, as the `Application.Outlook` object also doesn't have `.Inbox` or `.Logoff` methods - i.e. your code is completely incorrect and not based on the Outlook COM automation model.